# Why am I getting error "#let or #subject called without a block"?

Tags: ruby, rspec, proc

I wonder how to pass code to shared examples.

I have these specs (snipped)

```
let(:property) { subject.send(type) }

    context 'when one or both depending properties are not set' do
      shared_examples_for 'not set' do |init_proc|
        it "imperial.value returns nil" do
          init_proc.call
          expect(property.imperial.value).to eq(nil)
        end
        # 3 similar examples snipped
      end

      context "when neither is set" do
        include_examples 'not set', Proc.new { }
      end

      context "when #{type1.inspect} is not set" do
        include_examples 'not set',  # error in this line
          Proc.new { subject.send("#{type2}=", [100, :imperial]) }
      end

      context "when #{type2.inspect} is not set" do
        include_examples 'not set',
          Proc.new { subject.send("#{type1}=", [100, :imperial]) }
      end
    end
```

What is surprising me is the error I get:

```
RuntimeError:
   #let or #subject called without a block
```

I thought this would work. It's as if `Proc.new` calls subject right away, instead when I call `init_proc.call`. Is that what's going on?

If not, then what's causing the error?

PS. Question is not how to get this code to work. I got this code to work, I am only interested in explanation why I got the error before.